TEXTAFTER in online excel
I have below formula to show worksheet name in one of cells.
=TEXTAFTER(CELL("filename",A3),"]")
It works perfect for standalone application, however when is uploaded to sharepoint and opened from the web it displays #VALUE!
I found the below two solutions, but non of them works
= PART (CELL ("filename"; A1); FIND ("]"; CELL ("filename"; A1)) + 1; 255) = PART (CELL ("filename"; A1); FIND ("]"; CELL ("filename"; A1)) + 1; LENGTH (CELL ("filename"; A1)) - FIND ("]"; CELL ("filename"; A1)))

It is clearly written here that "filename" doesn't work in Excel for the web:

"filename"
Filename (including full path) of the file that contains reference, as
text. Returns empty text ("") if the worksheet that contains reference
has not yet been saved.
Note: This value is not supported in Excel for the web, Excel Mobile,
and Excel Starter.

You might consider using Office Script something like this:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A1").setValue(workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getName());
}

Result:


When using Excel online through SharePoint, certain functions behave differently, and in some cases, they might not be supported at all or return errors like #VALUE!.
What you can do is: Use a Defined Name

Go to Formulas > Define Name.
Set the name (e.g., SheetName).
Use the formula: =MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255).
In your cell where you want the sheet name, use =SheetName.

